# Symfony + mssql. Error tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate

Tags: sql-server, symfony, pdo, sqlsrv

I try to connect mssql to my symfony project, but get error SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate]"
So I want to set "TrustServerCertificate=yes" on pdo conception but can't figure out how it does on symfony
**I tried to write in .env**

DATABASE_MSSQL_URL="mssql://user:password@ip:port/db_name?Trusted_Connection=yes&Encrypt=yes&TrustServerCertificate=yes"

**in config/packages/doctrine.yaml:**

```
   dbal:
     jtl:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MSSQL_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_sqlsrv'
        server_version: '13'
        charset: utf8mb4
```

It did not help

Comment: Some driver interfaces are a bit flaky. Instead of `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` have you tried `TrustServerCertificate=true;` to see if it works?

Comment: Also, given the snake_case parameters in the doctrine file you could try `trust_server_certificate: true` there.

Comment: "mssql://user:password@ip:port/db_name;TrustServerCertificate=1" - it worked for me

Answer (score 5):

For me this options work well(project with sf 5.4):

```
dbal:
  connections:
    ...
    my_ms_sql_db:
      ...
      options:
        TrustServerCertificate: 1
```

Comment: it worked with sf6.2.9 too

Answer (score 2):

There is a connection option you can add. However, in my project it only worked with a explicit "url" and with the "TrustServerCertificate" option added to both:

```
dbal:
  connections:
    ...
    my_ms_sql_db:
      url: "sqlsrv://my_user:my_password@192.168.0.2:1434/my_db?TrustServerCertificate=yes"
      driver: pdo_sqlsrv
      charset: UTF-8
      host: ...
      port: ...
      ...
      options:
        TrustServerCertificate: yes
```

Comment: which Symfony and Doctrine did you use? It worked for me with `TrustServerCertificate: 1` using php 8.1.20, sf6.2.9 and doctrine 2.7

Comment: @ZoltánSüle currently it's PHP 7.4.29, Symfony 4.4, Doctrine 2.13. Looks like in the `url`, both "yes" and "1" will work. Haven't tested the "1" value in the `yml` syntax.

Comment: see also this answer for other versions/syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77225306/msodbc-driver-18-for-sql-servererror1416f086ssl-routinestls-process-serv

Answer (score 1):

In mssql connection url, properties can only be delimited by using the semicolon (';')

```
mssql://user:pass[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]];property=value[;property=value]]
```

Example:

```
DATABASE_URL=mssql://user:pass@serverName:port/db;**TrustServerCertificate=1**
```

Although it is jdbc, it also applies in this [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 1):

IDK with "mssql", but using `sqlsrv` driver you can try:

```ini
DATABASE_URL="sqlsrv://user:pass@ip:1433/dbName?charset=UTF-8&driverOptions[TrustServerCertificate]=1"
```

The "key" is `driverOptions` parameter.

If you check https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/configuration.html#custom-driver-options and the Doctrine file `vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/SQLSrv/Driver.php`, you have some clues about how to pass extra options to the driver.